# Separate .fit file to .feedme file

Tags: unix

I have images in my directory in the form

VELA02_a0.500_0005966__skipir_.fits

which need to be separated into .feedme files such as

VELA02_a0.500_0005966__skipir_.feedme

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
for i in *.fits; do n=`echo $i | sed s/\.fits/.feedme/`; mv $i $n; done
```

Assuming all the files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OS you are using. But Ubuntu OS has a `rename` command to meet such requirement. Its actually a perl script.

If you wanted to change the *.html file extension to .htm you can do something like this

```
rename 's/\.html$/\.htm/' *.htm
```